# Cannot select PDF from top to bottom

Tags: pdf, pdftotext

I'm using pdftotext to extract info from a pdf. Currently using the -raw option. I do have a few problems with the PDFs I'm working with. If I select the text from top to bottom it selects in the following fashion.

PDF content:

A

B

C

It selects A then C and then B. So when I extract the text it is presented in the same way. Is there a way to reformat the PDF so I can select the content from top to bottom?

NOTE: I'm aware that if I omit the "raw" option the layout will be preserved, but it seems to be buggy when the document includes tables so raw works better for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reformat the PDF so that the content is returned from top to bottom. This is not something that can be easily done using Adobe Acrobat or any other viewer that I am aware of and here is why.

From the documentation of pdftotext, the -raw option is defined as

> Keep the text in content stream order. This is a hack which often "undoes" column formatting, etc. Use of raw mode is no longer recommended.

"content stream order" is the important piece in the description.

In PDFs, the content on the page does not have to be written in the content stream (the instructions that are interpreted to display the page) in the order that a human would read the content when the page is rendered. The internals of PDFs do not care about the ordering, they were designed to reproduce the same visualization of a document on a variety of platforms. Since all that matters to PDF is the visualization, applications or libraries that write PDF tend to not order the content stream in any meaningful way.

So you can reorder the instructions in a content stream so that they are in the order a human would read them, it is not an easy task to do by hand and using a library that understands PDF to manipulate the content stream would be one way of doing this. Another way is to look for a more advanced tool to use to extract text from the PDF (there are a number of tools that will look at the placement of the content on a page rather than just where it appears in the content stream).

I am not aware of anything that will reorder the content stream in the PDF based on where the content appears on the page automatically though.

Comment: Are you aware of any specific tool that extracts PDF text based on the content placement?

Comment: There are a number of tools that will do this, there might even be some free ones out there. It depends on what type of tool you are looking for and how it fits into the larger project you are working on. I work for a company that makes PDF libraries for developers to integrate into their applications and our libraries offer the ability to extract text based on placement. There are some more advanced ones out there from companies that focus on this topic though, Abbyy (https://www.abbyy.com/en-us/) might be a good place to start.